# c# - Order a linq query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

For my generic grid I currently do this to activate the sorting:

```cs
Elements.OrderBy(column.SortExpression).AsQueryable();
```

In which `SortExpression` is of type `Func<T, object>` and column is a generic class `Column<T>`

I set SortExpression in a controller like this:

```cs
new Column<OrderViewData>{Key = "ShippingDate", SortExpression = e => e.ShippingDate}
```

**The 'OrderBy' causes an execution of the sql statement, which I don't want.**

So I'm trying to replace it with this:

```cs
Elements = from element in Elements
               orderby column.SortExpression
               select element;
```

Which doesn't trigger the sql execution.

Now, of course column `SortExpression` should be of another type. Only I can't really figure out what type it should be and how to set it on the generic class in the controller.

I should still be able to set `SortExpression` in a generic strong typed way of some sort.

Any suggestions on how I can order by an expression set somewhere else in the application, without executing the sql when applying the order to the IQueryable?

**@ Earwicker:**

This works:

```cs
Expression<Func<Employee, DateTime?>> sortexpression = e => e.BirthDate;

var db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var query = from e in db.Employees
                select e;
query = query.OrderBy(sortexpression);

int count = query.Count();
```

And generates:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [t0]
```

When I replace `DateTime`? in the first line with object:

```cs
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> sortexpression = e => e.BirthDate;
```

I get this exception :

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot order by type 'System.Object'

Now, you might say: "then just use `DateTime`?", but I'd like building the columns in my generic grid to require the least amount of code possible. I don't want people to have to type the whole `Expression<Func<Employee, some_type>>`. I want people to be able to just type something small like my first attempt `SortExpression = e => e.BirthDate`, where I take advantage of the generic Column class to define 'T'.

Do you think it would be possible to create some kind of extension that somehow gets the type of `e.BirthDate` and then casts the `Func<T, object>` to `Expression<Func<T,some_type>>` ?
Then I could do something in the internal code like:
Elements.OrderBy(column.SortExpression.FixCast())

I don't care much that my internal code is ugly or complex at this moment. I need to get the SQL queries right & take care of usability for developers using the grid.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

**@ earwicker 2:**

```cs
var gridBuilder = new RainbowGridBuilder<Employee> ("Examples_Employees") 
{
    
    Elements = GetEmployees(),
    //The elements (records) we will show in our grid. 
    
    //Define the columns for our grid.
    Columns = new List<Column<Employee >> 
    {
        new Column<Employee> 
        {
            Key = "EmployeeId", 
            //Key is used for sorting, selecting columns, ...
            
            Header = "Employee Id", 
            //The header of the column. Also used as caption in the column selection checkboxlist.
            
            ValueExpression = e => e.EmployeeID.ToString(), 
            
            //The Linq expression which will be executed on each element to fill the cell
            
            SortExpression = e => e.EmployeeID, 
            //The Linq expression by which to sort the elements in the grid. 
            
            Display = false
        }, //Is this column visible by default?
      
        new Column<Employee> 
        {
            Key = "Name",
            ValueExpression = e => 
                e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
            SortExpression = e => e.LastName
      } ,
    },

    // Some other properties here that are irrelevant.
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who gets a weird feeling from the word "Stackers" :P

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88947/what-should-visitors-to-stackoverflow-be-called

:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that achieves what I was after.

**Usage: Setting strong typed sortexpression on columns:**

```
Columns = new List<Column<Employee>>{
            new Column<Employee> {
                Key = "EmployeeId",   
                SortExpression = new SortExpression<Employee>(e => e.EmployeeID)
                // ... other irrelevant column properties ...  
            },
            new Column<Employee> {
                Key = "EmployeeBirthDate",      
                SortExpression = new SortExpression<Employee>(e => e.BirthDate)
            }
          };
```

**Underlying code**

These few lines in the "buildGrid()" method in class RainbowGridBuilder apply the sorting:

```
if (columnToSort != null) //sort the elements according to the set column key and the sortexpression
{
    var column = Columns.Where(c => c.Key == columnToSort).SingleOrDefault();
    if (column != null)
    {
        Elements = column.SortExpression.ApplySortExpression(Elements, descending);
    }
}
```

How it works:

Trough the use of overloaded constructors in the SortExpression class that I made I can set a private `Expression<Func<T, some_specific_Type>>`.

Inside the SortExpression class is a method ApplySortExpression that searches for a non-null private member and sorts accordingly:

```
public class SortExpression<T>
{
    private Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> DateTimeExpression { get; set; }
    private Expression<Func<T, int?>> intExpression { get; set; }
    private Expression<Func<T, string>> stringExpression { get; set; }

    public SortExpression(Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> expression)
    {
        DateTimeExpression = expression;
    }

    public SortExpression(Expression<Func<T, int?>> expression)
    {
        intExpression = expression;
    }

    public SortExpression(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
    {
        stringExpression = expression;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> ApplySortExpression(IQueryable<T> elements, bool? descending)
    {
        if (DateTimeExpression != null)
        {
            if (descending.HasValue && descending.Value)
                return elements.OrderByDescending(DateTimeExpression);
            else
                return elements.OrderBy(DateTimeExpression);
        }
        else if (intExpression != null)
        {
            if (descending.HasValue && descending.Value)
                return elements.OrderByDescending(intExpression);
            else
                return elements.OrderBy(intExpression);
        }
        else if (stringExpression != null)
        {
            if (descending.HasValue && descending.Value)
                return elements.OrderByDescending(stringExpression);
            else
                return elements.OrderBy(stringExpression);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Unsuported sortkey type");
    }
}
```

This solution may not be super clean under the hood, but it's the usability that I was after. The only change to the consuming code was to add "`new SortExpression<Employee>`".

Comment: Nice workaround, many thanks for sharing it. +2 (question, answer)

Answer (score 3):

SortExpression should be of the type `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

By making it a `Func<T, object>`, you cause the compiler to reduce it directly down to IL, ready to execute. Linq to SQL (or entities, or NHibernate, or whatever) will need the code captured in the form of an expression tree so it can translate it into SQL or some other query language for execution elsewhere. By assigning your lambda to `Expression<Func<...>>` you trigger compilation to an expression tree.

Does it work if you put this?

```
Elements = Elements.OrderBy(e => e.ShippingDate);
```

And how about this?

```
Expression<Func<OrderViewData, object>> sortExpression = e => e.ShippingDate;
Elements = Elements.OrderBy(sortExpression);
```

Based on your updated question, it sounds like you need to capture an expression with a static-typed return value, instead of `object`.

It's hard to know what would be the ideal arrangement for you, but in your original setup code you had:

```
new Column<OrderViewData>{Key = "ShippingDate", SortExpression = e => e.ShippingDate}
```

Suppose `Column` took two type parameters, `TElem` (the kind of value stored in the column) and `TSort` (the type of the value to sort by).

```
new Column<Employee, DateTime?> { SortExpression = e => e.BirthDate }
```

That doesn't look too unwieldy to me, and `SortExpression` would then just be:

```
Expression<Func<TElem, TSort>> SortExpression { get; set; }
```

Comment: How do I go about setting the SortExpression?
I changed the type like you said, and set sortexpression still like: SortExpression = e => e.OrderDate.

Comment: And I get:
 System.InvalidOperationException: Can not order on System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[GenericGridSpike.ViewData.OrderViewData,System.Object]].

Comment: I've added some intermediate steps to try, to see if we can diagnose it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't catch your reply in my recent events.. I'll edit my post to show what works

Comment: That sounds like the second best solution possible. :-) So you don't think it's possible to get the Type of the "e.BirthDate" part of the SortExpression? Because that would be the perfect solution in my case.

Comment: Otherwise I could probably also turn your solution into: "new Column<Employee> { SortExpression<DateTime?> = e => e.BirthDate }" with a generic SortExpression class as property of the Column class. Which is just a tad more readable.

Comment: Properties can't have their own type parameters, so that wouldn't quite work (methods can, obviously, but you can't called methods in an object initializer block).

Comment: If you write a static helper method that has the two type parameters, <TElem, TSort> and you have some useful parameter in terms of TElem, you can also have the big ugly expression as a 2nd parameter, and type inference should be able to work out what TSort is from the lambda. In fact this is exactly how OrderBy works, it's practically a description of Queryable.OrderBy. But the thing is, you'd need something like IQueryable<Employee> around to use as the first parameter, to fix that down, so that the lambda type inference has something to work from.

Comment: Sorry, but you lost me there :-). I can't seem to work out a solution like I intented. The problem is that the Column<..> is in IEnumerable<Column<T>>, so I can't really add a TSort at that level I think.. Still experimenting a bit

Comment: Could you tell me how the syntax of using your suggestion in the last comment might look?
I've edited my original post and added how the building up of the grid goes like, just to be clear what i'm after.

Comment: Check out my solution. Thanks for setting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the problem is due to the fact that you did OrderBy **before** converting to a Queryable. If you order on an IEnumerable<T>, then you need something to order first. Unlike IQueryable<T>, IEnumerable<T> does not build expression trees...it wraps one enumerable around the other. To gain the benefits of deferred execution, you need to make sure that your working with an IQueryable from the beginning. Converting to one after you have performed all of your filtering, sorting, etc. won't offer any benefit.

Comment: hm?
How is "query" in "var query = from e in db.Employees select e;" NOT an IQueryable?

Comment: I was talking about his original statement: Elements.OrderBy(column.SortExpression).AsQueryable();

Comment: Derp, hit enter too soon. I actually don't know what Elements is...I just assumed it was an IEnumerable. If it is already an IQueryable, then there was no need for AsQueryable...if it was an IEnumerable...performing OrderBy before converting to an IQueryable would generally cause a full set of data to be retrieved from the database...then sorted, rather than delaying the query to the database until later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution to this orderby problem:

```
        var SampleData = new SampleDataContext();

        var text = from i in SampleData.Events
                   select i;
        var text2 = text.OrderByDescending(i => i.id);
        return View(text2);
```