# How to make expression treat value type as a reference type?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql, expression

I wanted to store a collection of expressions accessing object's properties. For example:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Entity Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>>();
    list.Add(e => e.Id);
    list.Add(e => e.Name);
    list.Add(e => e.Parent);
    list.Add(e => e.Date);
    list.Add(e => e.Value);
    list.Add(e => e.Active);

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    list.ForEach(f => b.AppendLine(f.ToString()));

    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This code outputs:

```
e => Convert(e.Id)
e => e.Name
e => e.Parent
e => Convert(e.Date)
e => Convert(e.Value)
e => Convert(e.Active)
```

It does add `Convert` to value types.

As far as in the end I wanted to use those expressions with LINQ to SQL, I need not to have that `Convert` in expressions, for them to be successfully translated to SQL.

How can I achieve this?

P.S.: expressions from this collection are later used as arguments to `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods.

Comment: What harm is `Convert` doing there? A `Convert` operation is implicitly needed if you're going to box a value type if the expression is meant to be compiled. Or are you after merely getting the string representation of expression? One option is to make it fully generic by having a wrapper class around `Expression<S, T>` like `Wrapper<S>` and add wrappers to list instead of the expression itself. Would that work?

Comment: @nawfal I suppose `Convert` appears there due to the `Func` signature, as it's supposed to return `object`, and it does try to box the values. In a real aplication I do have a collection of expression, just as described in the OP. And they are actually used for `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` with LINQ to SQL `IQuerable<Entity>`. So I get an exception, saying, it failed to order by `object`

Comment: It's a good question then. You only care about OrderBy and ThenBy? Or would you want it for whole bunch of querying methods?

Comment: Its kind of dynamic Linq capability that you want here and there are some libraries available already (you can do a search). But the one I will suggest here is something like [anthony's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794039/661933). Basically the idea is the same as I mentioned in previous comment, backup wrapper instead of expression itself, and then delegate the task of doing Linq operations to the class itself. If you need to afford more methods, then thats more work, though. I will try to provide an answer sometime later.

Comment: @nawfal thanks. I'll consider that thoroughly as soon as possible, and write here then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a function generic in the proeprty type you can avoid the Convert:

```
private static LambdaExpression GetExpression<TProp>
                                    (Expression<Func<Entity, TProp>> expr)
{
    return expr;
}
```

then you can change the type of `list`:

```
var list = new List<LambdaExpression>();
list.Add(GetExpression(e => e.Id));
list.Add(GetExpression(e => e.Name));
```

This will require you to create your `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` expressions using reflection e.g.

```
LambdaExpression idExpr = list[0];
Type keyType = idExpr.ReturnType;

var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Entity), keyType);

var ordered = (IQueryable<Entity>)
                  orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, idExpr });
```

Comment: +1: I'll check your answer in detail...and write back

Answer (score 1):

I patched up a EF code first attempt at using your code like this

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Entity Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContext()
        : base(new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"),
            contextOwnsConnection: true)
    {
        // Using a SQL Compact database as backend
    }
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

and attempted some linq on the context

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>>();
    list.Add(e => e.Date);
    list.Add(e => e.Name);
    using (var c = new EntityContext())
    {
        //each time a new record is added
        var data = new Entity
        {
            Name = string.Format("Data{0}", c.Entities.Count()),
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };
        c.Entities.Add(data);
        c.SaveChanges();

        // sort by date
        foreach (var e in c.Entities.OrderBy(list.First().Compile()))
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Name, e.Date));

        // sort by name .. in reverse
        foreach (var e in c.Entities.OrderByDescending(list.Last().Compile()))
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Name, e.Date));

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

There were no issues running the code.

**UPDATE** The same holds true for LINQ to SQL: I built a table in a local SQL Server with the same structure as the class, and tried to `OrderBy` it : no problem.

My answer is "You don't need to worry about that".

Comment: LINQ to SQL seems to differ in this aspect from EF. At the very least, in your code you pass `Func<Entity, object>` to `OrderBy`, while in LINQ to SQL it needs `Expression<Func<Entity,object>>`....and it does throw an exception there...

Comment: +1: So, I have to worry about that :)....But in a long term perspective I do consider porting all code to EF...So I'll check your code, and remember about this in future

Comment: Glad to be helpful. FYI I tried running the same code on a LINQ to SQL dbml context (replicating the class on a sql server table) and it still worked perfectly.

Comment: It seems to me, I've found an explanation, why your code worked. The key difference is that you use `Enumerable.OrderBy`, while I was trying to use `Queryable.OrderBy`. For more info, please, see my answer below...Anyway, much thanks to you, as your answer made me see this, I greatly appreciate that!

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize it but it makes sense (I *was* a bit puzzled when I saw the code working, when I attempted to use it on the dbml I expected it to blow up but it didn't ... I'll no doubt keep that in mind if/when I'll have to use it in this fashion)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to the answer by Alex I found out for myself that, when ordering the data I can use two different methods, depending on the specified argument:

1. [Queryable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`
2. [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with `Func<TSource, TKey>`

When `Queryable.OrderBy` is used, LINQ compiles the `OrderBy` clause into the SQL statement, executed over the database. So when I try to give it a `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` that looks like `e => Convert(e.Field)`, LINQ throws an `InvalidOperationException`, saying `Cannot order by type 'System.Object'`.

When `Enumerable.OrderBy` is used, LINQ does not compile the `OrderBy` clause into the SQL query, but executes the current query and applies sorting on the enumerable of entities, returned by the query, in the program's memory. Here no problem with ordering by `Func<TEntity, object>`.

So I found two alternatives here:

1. Query the database without sorting and order the returned result set
2. Provide better expressions to LINQ, that it could compile the SQL query, and then apply sorting in the database layer; here the answer by Lee suggests one way..

In my exact case sorting is the last operation to execute, and I don't see much harm, if I order the result set in the programm's memory...I'm not going to expect huge amounts of data to be returned...

Though in a more common case, probably it's still better to do all possible operations in the database layer...

P.S.: [SO: Order a linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914681/order-a-linq-query) - a close discussion...