# What is the difference between Queryable.OrderBy and Enumerable.OrderBy?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Suppose I have a LINQ to SQL (or EntityFramework) data context (object context). I want to query some data from it and sort the result set. The query would look like:

```
using(var dc = new TestDataContext) // = new TestEntities)
{
    var query = dc.MyEntities.Where(e => /*my where clause*/)
                             .OrderBy(/*my sorting field*/)
                             .ThenBy(/*another sorting field*/);
    foreach(var entity in query)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of an argument different `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods may be used.

1. [Queryable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`
2. [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with `Func<TSource, TKey>`

In `DataContext.Log` one can see that `Queryable.OrderBy` compiles the given expression into the SQL statement executed over the database, while when using `Enumerable.OrderBy` LINQ actually does the sorting over the objects in the programm's memory, i.e. the query over the database is executed without sorting...

What are other possible peculiarities, I may come across?

This question arised after this: [SO How to make expression treat value type as a reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140696/how-to-make-expression-treat-value-type-as-a-reference-type/20183444#20183444)

Comment: What exactly is the question? What kind of peculiarities are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In `DataContext.Log` one can see that `Queryable.OrderBy` compiles the
>   given expression into the SQL statement executed over the database,
>   while when using `Enumerable.OrderBy` LINQ actually does the sorting
>   over the objects in the programm's memory,

That's the only difference. And because compiler can translate your lambda `Func<T>` into `Expression<Func<T>>` the `Queryable.OrderBy` will be used by default.

> When a lambda expression is assigned to a variable, field, or parameter whose type is `Expression<TDelegate>`, the compiler emits instructions to build an expression tree.
>
> *from [`Expression<TDelegate>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

If you really need to perform LINQ to Objects `Enumerable.OrderBy` call `AsEnumerable()` before `OrderBy` call.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that persistence frameworks such as NHibernate and Entity Framework have their own LINQ providers that traverse expression trees and build SQL queries. This is thanks to [*deferred execution*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Nothing actually happens with an `IQueryable` until something forces the provider to evaluate it.

On the other hand.. LINQ can do in-memory queries AFTER the above has taken place. Maybe this will make more sense:

```
var result = db.Entities.Table
               .Where(x => x.Id == 1) // SQL WHERE clause
               .OrderBy(x => x.Id)    // SQL ORDER BY clause
               .ToList()              // Query the database and store result
               .Sum(x => x.SomethingElse) // Sum the field in memory
               .ToList();                 // convert back to a list.
```

As you can see.. halfway through that chain the provider hits the database with a generated query. The `ToList()` call forces the provider to query the database for results. After that, it's all in-memory.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` instead of the first `ToList()` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @svick Does `AsEnumerable` force evaluation? Looking at it.. it appears that it just returns the original. I.e: `return source`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead `AsEnumerable` forces next method to be executed using LINQ to Objects. It can just return `source`, but because it returns it as `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`, next method will be resolved as `IEnumerable` extension method, what makes it LINQ to Objects call.